# Cancelling terms in Riemann curvature tensor derivation

Tags: general-relativity

I'm having trouble seeing how the the first term of the third bracket (line 3) cancels out when mu and nu are interchanged.

It's clear to me how the first term of the first bracket and how the entirety of the second bracket fall out by commuting partial derivatives/symmetry of the Christoffel symbol (torsion-free) respectively, but I can't seem to understand why that first term of the third bracket falls out.

Could someone please explain how it ultimately drops out?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the third line, there are three terms which have a single derivative on V:

$$
\Gamma^{\rho}_{\nu\sigma}\partial_\mu V^\sigma - \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda V^\rho + \Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\sigma}\partial_\nu V^\sigma 
$$
which is symmetric in $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$. I think you were missing a term from the first backet on line three.

Comment: precisely! I was missing the second term you'd get from the product rule of the partial acting on the second term of the first bracket! thank you for the response